# What happens with a table in a ui-view when the ui-view changed state?

Tags: angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ui-view inside a bootstrap Nav Tabs:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/product/list') }"><a data-toggle="tab" ui-sref="productList" ng-click="getProductsList()">Products</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/product/keywords') }"><a data-toggle="tab" ui-sref="productKeywordList" ng-click="getProductKeywordsList()">Keywords</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
              <div ui-view="productDetails"></div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

For each tab are separate views below:

productlist.html

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="tablescroll">
          <img ng-if="dataLoading || !productHasData || !isDataTable" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
          <table ng-show="!dataLoading && productHasData && isDataTable" id="productTable" class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Product Name</th>
                       <th>Product Description</th>
                       <th>Product Type</th>
                   </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="product in productsList" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
                      <td>{{ product.productName }}</td>
                      <td>{{ product.productDescription }}</td>
                      <td>{{ product.productType }}</td>
                   </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
```

keywordlist.html

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="tablescroll">
          <img ng-if="dataLoading || !productKeywordHasData || !isDataTable" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
          <table ng-show="!dataLoading && productKeywordHasData && isDataTable" id="productKeywordTable" class="table table-hover">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Product Name</th>
                      <th>Keyword</th>
                      <th>Comments</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="productKeyword in productKeywordsList" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
                      <td>{{ productKeyword.productName }}</td>
                      <td>{{ productKeyword.keyword }}</td>
                      <td>{{ productKeyword.comments }}</td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Each view renders about tens of thousands of data. It takes time to load each view initially. But when the data for each has already been loaded, changing tabs would also take time. And at times (usually at 3rd tab change) my browser crashes due to running out of memory:

[image]

What happens to a table in a ui-view when the application changes state? It looks like that the data is still there. But does ng-repeat still get triggered?

What is the best way to do this? Should I clear up the other table when I change state?

Is ngRoute a better choice for this case?

Answer (score 0):

> Each view renders about tens of thousands of data.

More likely than not, this is your problem.

From a UX perspective, how is a user even able to manage 10k+ screen elements? This type of data should use pagination and filters, in my opinion, without thinking about your exact use case.

Next, angular's performance really starts to degrade above about 2k watchers (this is arbitrary, but a good rule of thumb).

While the `ui-view` will be cleaned up on each view change, you also have to be aware that the data may still be "live" in your services. Additionally, there may be a moment where the new view is appended, prior to destroying the old view.

You should start inspecting your page to get some benchmarks—memory, # watchers, rendering time—to get an idea of how your code changes will improve your design.

Comment: I transform the table into Data Table (thru my onFinishRender directive) for my pagination and filters.

Comment: I am really new at using AngularJs. I am still in the experimental stage to understand each code. Thank you for your insights!

Comment: hi, I tried to count the watchers in my app and I only got 6..

I am using AngularJs 1.5.6